# gnuplot: line break following a comment line

Tags: gnuplot

Why this code doesn't work?

```
plot \
#sin(x),\
cos(x)
```

the error info is

```
plot 
     ^
"a.plt", line 3: function to plot expected
```

gnuplot --version

```
gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 0
```

Comment: There is a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34221042/gnuplot-disable-part-of-a-plot-command). Maybe the answer helps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That code doesn't work, because a `\` at the end of a comment line makes gnuplot treat the next line also as comment. See the documentation about comments.

Comment: Is it possible to comment only a line in a sequence like the one of the OP? I mean something like the `/*  */` of the C++ to individuate the start and the end of the comment? It could be cosy...

Comment: @Hastur No, that isn't possible.