# Gnuplot: Disable part of a plot command

Tags: gnuplot

Let us say I have following simple gnuplot file:

```
set term pdf
set output "test.pdf"

plot\
    sin(x),\
    cos(x),\
    0.5
```

Now I just want to temporarily comment the line with `cos(x),\`.

However, using the comment character # results in an erroneous gnuplot command.

I am looking for a solution without moving lines of code. I just want to use the toggle comment feature of my editor.

Comment: There is no way to get this, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/30868244/2604213

Comment: That's too bad. I think it would be a good extension to gnuplot to optionally disable line continuation in comments.

Comment: There were also discussions on the mailing list: http://gnuplot.10905.n7.nabble.com/line-continuation-of-comments-td11266.html http://gnuplot.10905.n7.nabble.com/Comments-and-continuation-lines-td19020.html

Comment: Actually, my first comment about extending gnuplot to optionally disable line continuation is a not sufficient extension to allow for what I have asked. Gnuplot commands must also be allowed to be on several lines without line continuation. This is currently also not valid gnuplot script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a workaround. You can parse the script dynamically to remove the lines with a `#` altogether. Using `grep`:

```
grep -v "#" script | gnuplot
```

will successfully parse this:

```
plot\
    sin(x),\
    #cos(x),\
    0.5
```

where `script` is the name of the file containing the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Although gnuplot does not directly support what you are asking for, you can probably build a workaround. 
As gnuplot does not plot undefined values, this might work

```
identity = 0
#identity= 1
name=identity ? "cos(x)" : ''

plot sin(x), (1/identity)*cos(x) t name
```

Depending on whether you toggle comments on or off, the variable `identity` will have the value `0` or `1`.
In the first case (i.e., `identity = 0`), the result of `(1/identity)` (and therefore of `(1/identity)*cos(x)`) is undefined and gnuplot will not plot it.
After removing the comment in the above example `identity` will equal `1`. In this case, the result of `(1/identity)` is `1`, and, therefore, `(1/identity)*cos(x)` is identical to `cos(x)`.

To show the correct title (`identity = 1`) or no title at all (if `identity=0`), I have added the line `name=identity ? "cos(x)" : ''`